# Keyframe extraction using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, keyframe

I'm trying to set up a video framework in MATLAB for which I need to know the key frames of a given video. I tried out ffmpeg and I was able to extract the key frames. I know I could call ffmpeg from MATLAB and go on with my life. I'd like to know the key frame indices and hence my requirement for a MATLAB solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [VideoReader class](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) to load videos in Matlab.

Comment: VideoReader would read frames from the video. I'm not sure if I can extract key frames from the video. Does it?

Comment: I don't know your exact set-up and file formats, so unfortunately I cannot tell you if it will solve your problem. However, you may want to have a look to the documentation.

Comment: Yep, I had a look at the docs. It can read different formats but does not provide a mechanism to extract key frames.

Comment: I am sorry to hear so. Let's hope somebody else can help you.